# install4J, windows 2008R2 and java 6 permission issues

Tags: install4j

We are using install4j to install our application on Windows 2008R2. With Java 1.4 installed the install4j effort works fine. with Java 6 installed the install4j effort results in permission issues with C:\Program Files(x86).

Can anyone comment on the different permissions Windows 2008 might require for an install4j executable when using java 6 compared to java 1.4?

FYI Windows 2008 64bit, java 32bit, install4j 32bit

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in permission handling between Java 1.4 and Java 6. Permissions in install4j are handled by the "Request privileges" action which is typically located in the "Startup" node of your installer. For installing into `C:\Program Files (x86)`, you need elevated privileges.

If your installer works with Java 1.4 and does not work with Java 6, there must be some other error. I would suggest to look at the file `.install4j/installation.log` for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am unable to find the .install4j/installation.log.

Comment: Additionally, I do not have a "Request Privileges" action in my Startup node.  I will add one and post the results.   --thank you